# Filter elements of object composed by objects by value, vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, object, functional-programming, reduce

I have this object with some values; among them a `byKey` object with some other objects:

```
const myObject = {
  byKey: {
    1: {
      id: "One",
      getIt: true,
    },
    2: {
      id: "Two",
      getIt: false,
    },
    3: {
      id: "Three",
      getIt: true,
    },
    4: {
      id: "Four",
      getIt: false,
    },
  },
  someOtherValue1: true,
  someOtherValue2: false,
};
```

I want to get a new object removing all the `byKey` objects with `getIt: false`, so I get:

```
const myResultObject = {
  byKey: {
    1: {
      id: "One",
      getIt: true,
    },
    3: {
      id: "Three",
      getIt: true,
    },
  },
  someOtherValue1: true,
  someOtherValue2: false,
};
```

I'm doing it this way:

```
const myObjectByKeyElementsArray = Object.values(myObject.byKey).filter(
  (item) => item.getIt === true
);

const myResultObject = myObjectByKeyElementsArray.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({
    ...myObject,
    byKey: {
      ...acc.byKey,
      [curr.id]: curr,
    },
  }),
  {}
);

console.log(myResultObject);
// const myResultObject = {
//   byKey: {
//     1: {
//       id: "One",
//       getIt: true,
//     },
//     3: {
//       id: "Three",
//       getIt: true,
//     },
//   },
//   someOtherValue1: true,
//   someOtherValue2: false,
// };
```

Works nicely, but is a bit verbose, and sometimes can get complex to read.
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could achieve what you're after is by using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the entries, you can remove the `[key, value]` elements where the value's `getIt` is `false`. Once you have filtered the entries to remove the unwanted key-value pairs, you can convert the entries back into an object by `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const myObject = { byKey: { 1: { id: "One", getIt: true, }, 2: { id: "Two", getIt: false, }, 3: { id: "Three", getIt: true, }, 4: { id: "Four", getIt: false, }, }, someOtherValue1: true, someOtherValue2: false, };

const res = {
  ...myObject,
  byKey: Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(myObject.byKey).filter(([, {getIt}]) => getIt)
  )
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

For better readability you can do something like this,

```js
let myObject = {
  byKey: {
    1: {
      id: "One",
      getIt: true,
    },
    2: {
      id: "Two",
      getIt: false,
    },
    3: {
      id: "Three",
      getIt: true,
    },
    4: {
      id: "Four",
      getIt: false,
    },
  },
  someOtherValue1: true,
  someOtherValue2: false,
};

let { byKey } = myObject;
let newByKey = {};
Object.keys(byKey).forEach(key => {
  if(byKey[key].getIt) {
    newByKey[[key]] = byKey[key];
  }
})
myObject = {...myObject, byKey: newByKey};
console.log(myObject);
```